# Wordpress question mark black diamonds

Tags: wordpress, character-encoding

i don't know why but some (not all) accents become black diamonds with question mark inside.
This problem drive me crazy.
My MySQL Database is utf-8 character and utf-8_general_ci collate.
I use charset utf-8 but if last character is an accent become a black diamond.
I really don't know why.

For example

Title: CTX-21 Alka + Incrementatore di alcalinità
Become: CTX-21 Alka + Incrementatore di alcalinit�

Title: Title: CTX-21 Alka + Incrementatore di alcalinità.
Become: Title: CTX-21 Alka + Incrementatore di alcalinità.

Lol.. why that??

Check my page as example:

https://www.elementoacqua.it/shop/prodotti-chimici/incrementatore-di-alcalinita-ctx-21-alka/

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I has a similar problem;

In wp-config.php, the Database Charset was empty, looking like this:

```
DB_CHARSET', ''
```

Therefore, I included the charset inside it:

```
DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'
```

Afterwards, I deactivated and activated the theme, cleared the cache (using WP Super Cache) and the issue fixed.

Comment: Just to be clear and not cause confusion, you specify the above charset in a define, like so: `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');`